# Как Tor находит узлы для построения цепи?

Tags: сеть, веб-сервер, ip, криптография, tor

**Tor**-клиент шлет зашифрованный трафик через цепочку серверов, при этом сам трафик шифруется открытыми ключами всех серверов. Вопрос: откуда клиент узнает **IP**-адрес первого сервера в цепочке? Откуда он вообще получает информацию о том, какие серверы доступны для построения цепочки? Откуда он получает их открытые ключи: обращаясь к самим серверам или оттуда же, откуда берет **IP**-адресы доступных серверов? И, пожалуй, самое главное: как при обеспечении всех этих процедур (до отправки самого трафика по цепочке) сохраняется анонимность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При старте TOR-клиент обращается к одному из "корневых" серверов сети, откуда получает т.н. "консенсус". Консенсус содержит список публичных узлов сети, которые можно использовать для построения цепочки. В консенсусе ищутся Guard-узлы, один из которых будет первым в цепочке. Также ищутся промежуточные и выходные узлы.